# bash, how to retrieve the value after N occurrences of a delimiter?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I need some help with bash on Linux; I need to find a command that performs the following operation.

I have a file where the fields are separated by the | symbol, and I have to select the values that appear after 51 occurrences of that symbol and before the appearance of the following one.

This bash command, if applied to the following file, would return/select just the value **0.02468**

File sample:

`AB=0.543;AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=1;BaseQRankSum=-8.244;DB;DP=178;DS;Dels=0;FS=0.568;GC=36;HRun=0;HaplotypeScore=3.5479;MQ=59.09;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.171;QD=12.69;ReadPosRankSum=-0.923;SB=-1203.97;SBD=0.83;VQSLUD=7.2941;culprit=MQRankSum;set=GGSKSNP;CSQ=C|missense_variant|MODERATE|SLC7A2|ENSG00000003487|Transcript|ENST00000001234|protein_coding|7/8||ENST00000001234.10:c.1223G>C|ENSP00000001234.10:p.Cys416Ser|1234|1234|123|C/S|tGt/tCt|rs1234567||1||SNV|HGNC|123456|YES|||CCDS12345.1|ENSP00000004531|P52569||UPI1234A123A4||Ensembl|G|G|||tolerated(0.41)|benign(0)|Pfam_domain:PF12345&hmmpanther:PTHR12345&hmmpanther:PTHR12345:SF242&TIGRFAM_domain:TIGR00906|||0.0613|0|0.0202|0.2421|0|0.0501|0.0006809|0.0003488|0.02468|`

Can anyone help me with this bash command?
I tried to look it up online but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed -E`:

```sh
sed -E "s:^([^\|]*\|){51}([^\|]*).*$:\2:"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVENa9swFPwzozSFKJL8baGBYydOaZM5UVoYyxrcREvN4g8sZVD29teXyUnbjcIkkO7dnd4JScltf1cdjkcVPlx@eVjB16sV9H465NdL1UNXH8IVDY/HaMgxcmyLRTEnLBp3FYtmBg9zJeeLvPouDiXv@4jaNkuGLMk48XyWCJbIveKYjUV3xvVZGnPLZZPFoTLsJG/2tX5upNjUreSWyfACNp1zJ0C4A9iYpn/7E0Q8wuYJJxS5AVvIfJvV6k3GKKAWE0NjpNhCgWdwYnJ9i93Pxe1dwj1EA5uwzWHftIXmb62ZkpqnqbgRs4zFYs5jKAulZKXk@kfeFnmlYfopGS2i5QjEbexFFEYzkeLzsGzfg2WbV2rTFo3upOWLRKhlQ9PWWhbVelNvi2oH3sCH9x5EcLhBhFIr/Rh3YvZObFD8rGziCtnCqenrAvFAgE71QMcaWtXRjusBEAAxu4dJOovhTMLnkQCAOE7EiUDk3yDbsQhkDnXcAOAuu@4skVki21zWPET5uIfUTABd72Wba7m9xMgmPXiUVbGrLnEPsm95ud7WZV5UYTY@hVw8lWVj3u9JtmG2nCz@T4ZiTG16sbxOF@No@tqmKzEOsGuCMcIusQB3gGJqNnOAnGsHk27D2PVxcEbmW/yT1XZ9@F03uqgrdeyP/gA)

Alternatively, you can use pure BASH:

```sh
read temp
for i in {1..51}; do
    temp="${temp#*|}"
done
echo "${temp%%|*}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFrb9owFP3Or4jYWrWVZmznjeVJIYFQrbCAaaV9QgHcEo08lJhKVS@/nTnQdlOlOZLvuecc35M4q7TZHo@1TDeGknnVeSxrIzOywnglCNnkwIxN2TH0alXe/fra1i83cOh2NmUhO3K9LY03@uICbg7d4zEYcIxsy2RByAkLRm3HgqnGg7SRs3la/Bb7nH/zELUsFg1YlHDieiwSLJK7hmM2Eu0Zx2NxyE2Hjef7QrPjtNqV6qWSYl3Wkps6w/XZZMZtH@EWYG2a/J1PEHEJm0WcUOT4bK4/MimbDxkjn5pMDLSRYhP5rsaRzvVM9jATd/cRdxH1LcLW@11VZ4p/jGaNVDyOxQ8xTVgoZjyEPGsaWTRy@ZzWWVoomPyMhvNgMQRxF7oBheFUxPi8TMtzYVGnRbOus0q10uJNItS0oKpLJbNiuS43WfEEbs@Dzx5EcH@NCKVm/D1sxeSTWKHwpbGII2QNp6HvG4Q9ASpWPRUqqJuWth0XgACI6QOM42kIZxJ@DQUAhGEkTgQi/wZZtkkgsant@AD3yW1rCfQWWPpl9UXkqx3E@gFQ5U7WqZKbK4wscg0rWWRPxRW@huQxzZebMk@zop@MTiGX2zyv9P1tZd1PFuP5/8m@GFGLXi5u4/komLyPaVuMfezoYIywQ0zALaCY6qIPkHNvY9IWjB0P@2ekf4t3slqOB38A)

`awk`, `IFS` and `cut` approaches are given above.

Personally I agree that `cut` should be the winner, for it`s much simpler to remember than any other method listed in the thread.

Answer (score 7):

Use `cut`. It is used, well, to "cut" the string between delimeters. Ex:

```
cut -d"|" -f52 <<EOF
AB=0.543;AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=1;BaseQRankSum=-8.244;DB;DP=178;DS;Dels=0;FS=0.568;GC=36;HRun=0;HaplotypeScore=3.5479;MQ=59.09;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.171;QD=12.69;ReadPosRankSum=-0.923;SB=-1203.97;SBD=0.83;VQSLUD=7.2941;culprit=MQRankSum;set=GGSKSNP;CSQ=C|missense_variant|MODERATE|SLC7A2|ENSG00000003487|Transcript|ENST00000001234|protein_coding|7/8||ENST00000001234.10:c.1223G>C|ENSP00000001234.10:p.Cys416Ser|1234|1234|123|C/S|tGt/tCt|rs1234567||1||SNV|HGNC|123456|YES|||CCDS12345.1|ENSP00000004531|P52569||UPI1234A123A4||Ensembl|G|G|||tolerated(0.41)|benign(0)|Pfam_domain:PF12345&hmmpanther:PTHR12345&hmmpanther:PTHR12345:SF242&TIGRFAM_domain:TIGR00906|||0.0613|0|0.0202|0.2421|0|0.0501|0.0006809|0.0003488|0.02468|
EOF
```

will output the expected.

Below are some other commonly used commands for such issue.

We can use `awk`:

```
awk -vFS="|" '{print $52}'
```

We can read the string into array and output the 51 value:

```
IFS="|" read -r -a arr
echo "${arr[51]}"
```

We can use read to omit first 51 values, like:

```
IFS="|" read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ val _
echo "$val"
```

Comment: `-vFS="|"` (no space after `-v`) is gawk-only. Change it to `-v FS="|"` and it'll work in any awk. Having said that, you should just do `-F'|'` instead, also in any awk.

Comment: The last example has only 50 `_` but more importantly, you need an extra `_` after `val` or it would pick up any junk after.

Answer (score 2):

Another strange way with `sed`:

```
sed 's/|[^|]*//52g;s/.*|//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Ed Morton advice.
The simplest and most elegant approach is `awk`:

```
    awk -F'|' '{print $52}'
```

#### Explanation:

`-F'|'` cause the default field separator to be `|` symbol.

`'{print $52}'` print field number 52.